# Determining 2D location of item from a photograph taken from a fixed camera

Tags: 2d, perspectivecamera, photogrammetry

I have a photograph showing two items, a and b, in a scene. I know the distance to a (if this helps). The camera is at a fixed location, and its height, focal length and direction angle are known. Assume the ground is completely flat.

All that is known about b are its x,y coordinates on the photograph.

I want to find the coordinates of item b and show this on a 2d map.

[Camera View http://www.spannerworx.com/images/perspective.jpg](http://www.spannerworx.com/images/perspective.jpg)

[Side profile http://www.spannerworx.com/images/perspective2.jpg](http://www.spannerworx.com/images/perspective2.jpg)

[What I want to achieve http://www.spannerworx.com/images/perspective3.jpg](http://www.spannerworx.com/images/perspective3.jpg)

Is this possible, if so please advise me on what calculations I need to achieve this?

Comment: It appears in your diagrams that b is a translation of a. Is that true?

Comment: Possible duplicate found here:
http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12434/how-do-i-calculate-the-distance-of-an-object-in-a-photo

Comment: If b is a translation of a then db = da ( xa / xb ), where xa and xb are the size of the objects (an edge, for example).

Comment: Hi Adam, no its not a translation, b is a separate object at an unknown location. a is an object that I know the distance to, and was wondering if I could use that as a control point to help calculate b?

Comment: Hi Armen, in this question I have one (or potentially more) control points i.e. box a, that I can use to help calibrate this and calculate the position of b. I am seeking the topdown xy and not just the distance.